# Little changing of limit has great affect for performance of query. Why?

Tags: mysql

I have simple query with `where`, `order by` and `limit` (there is not filter by 'upped' in `where` section):

```
SELECT t.id FROM table t  WHERE ... and t.status in (2, 15) and ... order by t.upped desc LIMIT 36;
```

It is executing ~1.35s, and there are 26 rows as result. Explain:

- type: index
- key: upped
- key_len: 9
- rows: 2445
- filtered: 88.43
- extra: using where

If I change `limit` value to <=26, the query is executing ~200ms. Explain:

- type: index
- key: upped
- key_len: 9
- rows: 1766
- filtered: 122.42
- extra: using where

If I change `limit` value to >=40, same query is executing ~200ms. Explain:

- type: range
- key: status
- key_len: 4
- rows: 2160
- filtered: 100.00
- extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort

As we can see, little changing of `limit` value has great affect for performance. If `limit` is specified from 27 to 39 (inclusive), then query is very slow, otherwise - relatively fast. This strange behavior started unexpectedly several days ago. What could be reason of it?

I use innodb engine, there are about 248285 total rows in table. Version of  mysql is 5.6.23. We have ssd.

Comment: Sounds like after the 25th row, going in order of `upped`, there are a LOT of rows with non-status-2-or-15 it has to scan through. Is this correct?

Comment: How is the index set up on `t.upped`, does it match `DESC`?

Comment: @lc No, it's impossible in our case, because `limit 26` is fast too. Actually, I don't understand why in `limit 40` mysql use `status` index and in `limit 39` - not.

Comment: Sorry didn't get that it had only 26 rows. I think limit <= 26 is stopping the output once it has scanned and returned 26 rows, and limits 26-40 are causing a full index scan? Must be something up with the selectivity of the two indexes or maybe even something else in your query you've snipped that's interacting. What is the most selective criteria in your where clause that causes only 26/248285 rows to be returned?